# How to Draw on android ImageView after scaling it?

Tags: java, android, canvas, imageview, ontouch

I have an ImageView and i want to zoom/drag on by two fingers and draw on it using one finger , but after scaling ImageView , bitmap coordinates and ImageView coordinates doesn't match , to solve this i provided onTouch like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
    final int NONE = 0;
    final int DRAW = 1;
    final int PINCH = 2;
    float x,y;

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawStartX = event.getX();
            drawStartY = event.getY();
            imageMode = DRAW;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //drag
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());

            x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
            y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
            oldDistance = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            if (oldDistance > 5f) {
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                mid.set(x / 2, y / 2);
                imageMode = PINCH;
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            imageMode = NONE;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            imageMode = NONE;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (imageMode == DRAW) {
                float drawEndX = event.getX();
                float drawEndY = event.getY();
                drawTest(drawStartX/bitmapScale - xTranslate, drawStartY/bitmapScale- yTranslate,drawEndX/bitmapScale - xTranslate,drawEndY/bitmapScale - yTranslate,0);
            } else if (imageMode == PINCH) {
                x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                float newDistance = (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                if(newDistance > 5f) {
                    //drag

                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);

                    //zoom
                    float scale = (newDistance / oldDistance);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);

                }
                //get matrix
                float[] mat = new float[9];
                matrix.getValues(mat);
                bitmapScale = mat[0];
                xTranslate = mat[2];
                yTranslate = mat[5];

            }
            break;
    }
    view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
    return true;
}
```

drawTest is just a void that draws a line.

[pic](http://8pic.ir/images/tdkqm8veus2l6kq9vfbs.png)

in before scale picture i drag my finger on imageview and line drawn in exact position , but after scaling i dragged on same position but result is not right

but it's not working properly. how can i fix it ?

Comment: How is it not working properly? What does it not do?

Comment: main post updated + picture